# SRID issue on insertion

Tags: postgis, srid

I have a table with a point geometry defined as   "geom geometry(Point,28355)"
I am trying to insert data using the following:

```
INSERT INTO tmpwatscint ( scgid, pipeid, geom )
     SELECT s.gid, p.pipe_id, ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_LineInterpolatePoint(p.geom,ST_LineLocatePoint (p.geom,st_startpoint(s.geom))),28355)) newgeom
       FROM "tmpWatPipe" p, "tmpWatServCon" s
       WHERE s.pipe_id = p.pipe_id ;
```

When I run the select statement on its own, it runs fine, however, when I try to insert the data I get an error:

> ERROR:  Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (28355)

I am running POSTGIS="2.3.2 r15302"

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. For the insert statement all I had to do was to remove the **ST_AsText()** function.